# iOS5.0 MFMailComposerViewController in UIPopoverController animates off screen when keyboard pops up

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have an app that works just fine on iOS4.x, and in most ways on iOS5.0.  I have, however, noticed a problem with my "send email" function.

I have an MFMailComposerViewController in a UIPopoverController for an iPad.  This works just fine on iOS4.x, but on iOS5.0 when the keyboard pops up to enter (for example) the destination email address, the UIPopoverController animates off the screen.  When the keyboard is dismissed the UIPopoverController animates back onto the screen.  Looks nice, but not terribly useful.  This does not happen on iOS4.x.

I have tried changing the content size of the UIPopoverController so that the keyboard doesn't cover any part of the popover but it still navigates off the screen.  Code snippet below.  I have to think it's something obvious that I'm not seeing.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I should add that I see this behavior in the simulator during testing - I don't have an iPad running iOS5.0.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController;

mailController = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailController setSubject:@"email subject"];
[mailController setMessageBody:@"email message body" isHTML:NO];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:self];

mailPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: mailController];
[mailPopoverController setDelegate:self];

[mailPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(keyWindow.bounds.size.width / 2.0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                     animated:NO];
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Would you mind filing a radar with a sample project that works on 4.3 but shows the problem on 5.0? Let me know the radar number once you've filed it.

Comment: Bug report #11343685 submitted.